# How to compute the mean of n values around a value with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, math, data.table, tidyverse

Let's say we have a vector `c(3,6,1,5,8,2,4)` and for each value I want to get the mean of the sub-vector of the 2 previous values and the 3 posterior values (so the `N` for the mean would be 2+1+3=6).

```
3 --> NA NA 3 6 1 2 --> NA
6 --> NA 3 6 1 5 8 --> NA
1 -->  3 6 1 5 8 2 --> 4.166667
5 -->  6 1 5 8 2 4 --> 4.333333
8 -->  1 5 8 2 4 NA --> NA
2 -->  5 8 2 4 NA NA --> NA
4 --> ... NA --> NA
```

so the output I'm interested in is `NA NA 4.17 4.33 NA NA`. (maybe with the extreme values there are also other options like smaller means `3 --> 3 6 1 2 --> 3` or imputing zeroes by NA's... ?)

Let's say now that I have a data frame with a column as the input vector `data.frame(x = c(3,6,1,5,8,2,4))` and now I want to build another column like the output vector, so the output data frame is `data.frame(x = c(3,6,1,5,8,2,4), y = c(NA, NA, 4.17, 4.33, NA, NA))`.

Are there functions to do this, maybe with base R, `tidyverse`, `data.table` or others?

More generally, could I try to make the average not only through rows but also across a specified set of columns, so if I want the average for the given row, 2 up and 3 down (6 rows) and 5 columns, the `N` would be 6*5=30?

As an example for this, if I want the mean for the 2 previous and 3 posterior rows of variables `drat` and `wt` of `mtcars`:

```
> mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

The output for car `Lotus Europa` (4th line by the end) would be the mean of 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62, 3.54, 1.935, 2.14, 1.513, 3.17, 2.77 and 3.57.

**Update:** thanks to those exposing me I am looking for a "rolling mean".

Comment: What you are asking for is called a "rolling mean." If you search/google that, you'll likely find something helpful.

Comment: The last part of the question regarding columns is unclear. Please provide an example with input and output to illustrate.

Comment: you could make your own rolling mean function like this `mav <- function(x,n=3){filter(x,rep(1/n,n), sides=1)}` where `n` is the width of the moving average

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Example provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rollmean` like this. `rollmean` and even more so, `rollapply`, have a number of arguments to customize the result.

```
library(zoo)
DF <- data.frame(x = c(3,6,1,5,8,2,4)) # test data

transform(DF, mean = rollmean(x, 5, fill = NA))
##   x mean
## 1 3   NA
## 2 6   NA
## 3 1  4.6   <-- mean(DF$x[1:5])
## 4 5  4.4   <-- mean(DF$x[2:6])
## 5 8  4.0   <-- mean(DF$x[3:7])
## 6 2   NA
## 7 4   NA
```

Here is a variation in which if there are fewer than 5 elements in the window centered at the current point it will take the mean of whatever is available rather than giving NA.

```
transform(DF, mean = rollapply(x, 5, mean, partial = TRUE))
##   x     mean
## 1 3 3.333333   <-- mean(DF$x[1:3])
## 2 6 3.750000   <-- mean(DF$x[1:4])
## 3 1 4.600000   <-- mean(DF$x[1:5])
## 4 5 4.400000   <-- mean(DF$x[2:6])
## 5 8 4.000000   <-- mean(DF$x[3:7])
## 6 2 4.750000   <-- mean(DF$x[4:7])
## 7 4 4.666667   <-- mean(DF$x[5:7])
```

To get the mean of everything from the 2 prior to 3 posterior of wt and drat we can use the fact that the mean of the mean is the overall mean.  Using list for the width argument of rollapply tells it to regard the vector as postiion offsets.

```
transform(mtcars, mean = rollapply((drat + wt)/2, list(seq(-2, 3)), mean, fill = NA))
```